# UIImageview and UItextview in table view cells

Tags: ios, uitableview, constraints

I have a table view cell that may or may not have images , but always has the textview. Both are displayed inline with each other horizontally, with image(if there) appearing on left  and then textview. Else if no image , just the textview on left. I have it success with just the text view. 
I am trying to set the constraint on image by pinning the leading and top constraints to superview. The leading constraint of textview is pinned to the trailing edge of image view . The image view(if there) is still appearing on the textview. It's not shifting to right . Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add leading, top and bottom constraint to imageView.
[image]

Now apply width constraints to imageView.

Now Drag a TextView and add leading constraint to imageView, top, bottom and trailing constraint as shown below.

[image]

Finally, create a IBOutlet to the imageView's width constraint. In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` if the cell needs to show the image then set the width constraint to whatever the width you wanna set to else set it to 0. Thats all. TextView will automatically move to left if there is no image and will be placed next to imageView if cell has any

```
//if cell has image
cell.imageViewWidthConstarint.constant = 82

//if cell does not show image
cell.imageViewWidthConstarint.constant = 0
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was not setting the constraint to the width.